# Which set did this assembly came from?

Tags: set-identification

Does anyone know which set did this came from? I got a bundle without instructions, some of it's partially built. I have no idea how to finish it for my kids.

[image]

Comment: Hi Pavel and welcome to Bricks.SE! Rin Rio-Oki has already answered the first question ("Does anyone know which set did this came from?"), to the second ("I have no idea how to finish it for my kids.") I'd recommend giving this and the entire lot to the kids and let them finish / alter / disassemble it as they see fit. Quite possibly they will end up having a lot more fun than if you handed them a completed official set.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a custom build, so no instructions.

I'm basing this answer off two parts in the pic:

- [*Part #6046 - Brown Bar 9 x 13 Grille,*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6046&name=Bar%209%20x%2013%20Grille&category=%5BBar%5D#T=C&C=8) appears in *[six sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6046&in=S)* with this color, and none of the sets seem to have a sub-build of this prison.

  [image]

and

- [*Part #2431px5 - Tile 1 x 4 with 'KEEP OUT' Pattern*,](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431px5&name=Tile%201%20x%204%20with%20%27KEEP%20OUT%27%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C) appears in *[three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2431px5&in=S)* with none of them resembling a hidden sub-build of this cage design.

  [image]

Comment: Also, not really lego quality build, too random

Comment: Thank you. It is likely the person I got the lot from from built it himself. I was just wondering as I wanted to complete it for my kids. THANK YOU !

Comment: @Pavel You can [accept this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as a great way to say thank you also.

Comment: @Pavel, You're welcome!